# Rewrite first folder to GET param for all php files

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am desperately looking for a rule to achieve the following:

Input URL request would be:

```
http://myserver.com/param/other/folders/and/files.php
```

It should redirect to

```
http://myserver.com/other/folders/and/files.php?p=param
```

similarly the basic index request

```
http://myserver.com/param/
```

would redirect to

```
http://myserver.com/?p=param
```

All my php files need the parameter, wherever they are. It'd be nice if JS and CSS files would be excluded but I guess it doesn't really matter since the /file.css?p=param would just be ignored and not cause a problem. I have found rules to map a folder to the GET parameter but none of them are working for php files deeper than the index file on the root level. Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Do you want to redirect or rewrite the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/(\w+)\/(.*)`

with

`http:\/\/\1/\?p=\2\/\3`

example regex page at https://regex101.com/r/sU6lR9/1